# Agrupar Valores Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Caros, tenho uma tabela com a configuração:

```
Tipo Medida Valor
1      0.2  5.00
1      0.4  6.00
1      0.1  5.00
1      0.3  5.00
2      0.1  3.00
2      0.2  3.00
2      0.3  5.00
2      0.4  5.00
```

Gostaria de agrupar os valores onde devem conter o mesmo tipo, um valor minimo e máximo para este tipo tendo em vista que o valor é o mesmo. O resultado seria algo do tipo:

```
Tipo Minimo Maximo Valor
  1   0.1     0.3  5.00
  1   0.4     0.4  6.00
  2   0.1     0.2  3.00
  2   0.3     0.4  5.00
```

Obrigado

Comment: O que você já tentou até agora? Que problemas encontrou?

Comment: Olá, @Thiago. É de bom grado que, ao postar uma pergunta, você poste também trechos de código ou explique o que você já tentou. Do jeito que você postou a pergunta, você simplesmente está terceirizando o trabalho e isso não é o que queremos na comunidade :)

Comment: Ok, entendo seu comentario, concordo e peço desculpas, vou me atentar a esse fato. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que sua tabela se chame "tabela", e que seu gerenciador de banco de dados suporte as funções de agregação MIN e MAX (mysql e postgres suportam), a seguinte query deve resolver seu problema.

```
SELECT tipo, MIN(medida) AS minimo, MAX(medida) AS maximo, valor
FROM tabela
GROUP BY tipo, valor
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado.